# Unable to update std::variant in consteval context

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, std-variant, consteval

I was writing a compile-time parser but I am stuck on a problem which I don't know how to solve in C++. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, version 17.8.3 (latest).

This is the code which is giving me a compiler error:

```
#include <array>
#include <variant>

using namespace std;

enum class TokenErrors
{
    UNINITIALISED,
    TK_ERROR_SYMBOL,
    TK_ERROR_PATTERN,
    TK_EOF
};

enum class MyTokenType
{
    TK_SYMBOL
};

template <typename TokenType, int num_states>
struct Lexer
{
    std::array<TokenType, num_states> final_states;
};

static consteval auto foo()
{
    auto lxr = Lexer<std::variant<MyTokenType, TokenErrors>, 5>{};
    for (auto &x: lxr.final_states)
        x = TokenErrors::UNINITIALISED;
    return lxr;
}

int main()
{
    auto res = foo();
}
```

I tried running this code. Visual Studio is giving me this error while compiling:

```
Build started at 17:22...
1>------ Build started: Project: EfficientCompiler, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Scanning sources for module dependencies...
1>main.cpp
1>C:\Users\Aakash\source\repos\EfficientCompiler\EfficientCompiler\main.cpp(35,19): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'Lexer<std::variant<MyTokenType,TokenErrors>,5>'
1>C:\Users\Aakash\source\repos\EfficientCompiler\EfficientCompiler\main.cpp(35,19):
1>Invalid aggregate initialization
1>  C:\Users\Aakash\source\repos\EfficientCompiler\EfficientCompiler\main.cpp(35,19):
1>  'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'MyTokenType'
1>      C:\Users\Aakash\source\repos\EfficientCompiler\EfficientCompiler\main.cpp(35,19):
1>      Too many braces around initializer for 'MyTokenType'
1>  C:\Users\Aakash\source\repos\EfficientCompiler\EfficientCompiler\main.cpp(35,19):
1>  'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'MyTokenType'
1>      C:\Users\Aakash\source\repos\EfficientCompiler\EfficientCompiler\main.cpp(35,19):
1>      Too many braces around initializer for 'MyTokenType'
1>  C:\Users\Aakash\source\repos\EfficientCompiler\EfficientCompiler\main.cpp(35,19):
1>  'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'MyTokenType'
1>      C:\Users\Aakash\source\repos\EfficientCompiler\EfficientCompiler\main.cpp(35,19):
1>      Too many braces around initializer for 'MyTokenType'
1>  C:\Users\Aakash\source\repos\EfficientCompiler\EfficientCompiler\main.cpp(35,19):
1>  'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'MyTokenType'
1>      C:\Users\Aakash\source\repos\EfficientCompiler\EfficientCompiler\main.cpp(35,19):
1>      Too many braces around initializer for 'MyTokenType'
1>  C:\Users\Aakash\source\repos\EfficientCompiler\EfficientCompiler\main.cpp(35,19):
1>  'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'MyTokenType'
1>      C:\Users\Aakash\source\repos\EfficientCompiler\EfficientCompiler\main.cpp(35,19):
1>      Too many braces around initializer for 'MyTokenType'
1>C:\Users\Aakash\source\repos\EfficientCompiler\EfficientCompiler\main.cpp(35,16): error C7595: 'foo': call to immediate function is not a constant expression
1>Done building project "EfficientCompiler.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 17:22 and took 01.116 seconds ==========
```

When I convert the signature of function `foo()` to  `static constexpr auto foo()`, the code compiles fine.

I am stuck on this problem, because as far as I know, `std::variant` is `constexpr` compatible (and it is compiling fine in `constexpr` context too) and it should not result in this error in `consteval`. Can someone help me here?

Comment: I am using MSVC compiler (the default compiler for visual studio community for C++), with the following information: `Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.38.33133 for x86`

Comment: But in any case, your code is fine. This must be a bug in MSVC or the MS standard library implementation.

Comment: Do you know how to report this or get it resolved? I am currently using a workaround for this (Building lexer using consteval and explicitly updating final_states in constexpr context), but would like to get it resolved

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/how-to-report-a-problem-with-the-visual-cpp-toolset?view=msvc-170

Comment: This does appear to be a bug in the MSVC compiler. I get the same error messages in VS2022.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, your code looks fine and this appears to be a bug in the MSVC compiler (which still persists in the version that ships with the 'latest' Visual Studio 2022). However, this question does not have the [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) tag and I'm not going to try to give an authoritative explanation for *why* I consider it a bug (other than the fact that your code compiles on every other compiler I have tried).

The strictly correct way to fix this is to file a bug report with the Visual Studio team and wait for them to fix the problem. But that could be a (very) long wait.

In the meantime, I will suggest a possible workaround …

Some investigations revealed that, in your code, what appears to be upsetting/confusing the MSVC compiler is the attempt to initialize the elements of the `final_states` array with values that are **not the first variant type**. Thus, if you change the `x = TokenErrors::UNINITIALISED;` line in the `for` loop to `x = MyTokenType::TK_SYMBOL;`, your code then compiles. However, this makes a *significant* – and very likely *undesirable* – change to the code base.

An alternative is to redefine the order of the `std::variant` types, so that `TokenErrors` becomes the first (i.e. *default*) object type. (This may also be undesirable, but it has less *observable* effects that the previous suggestion.) The following version of your `foo` function compiles with the MSVC compiler in the VS-2019 (142) Toolset (with all other code being left unchanged from that you have posted):

```cpp
static consteval auto foo()
{
    auto lxr = Lexer<std::variant<TokenErrors, MyTokenType>, 5>{};// Swap type order
    for (auto& x : lxr.final_states) {
        x = TokenErrors::UNINITIALISED; // Now first variant type!
    }
    return lxr;
}
```

This may also not be an 'acceptable' change. If so, please let me know and I will attempt to find alternative workarounds. I have already tried many other tricks, including creating a local, `const` object of the appropriate `std::variant` type and using that to initialize the `x` in the loop, but all these attempts have (so far) been unsuccessful.

---

Here is one of those attempts, using the `explicit` constructor of `std::variant` that takes a `std::in_place_index<n>` as its first argument; with this, the code as presented compiles but, if the first line is replaced with the (commented-out) second, it fails with the error message you have cited:

```cpp
static consteval auto foo()
{
    const std::variant<MyTokenType, TokenErrors> var{ std::in_place_index<0>, MyTokenType::TK_SYMBOL };     // Works
//  const std::variant<MyTokenType, TokenErrors> var{ std::in_place_index<1>, TokenErrors::UNINITIALISED }; // Fails
    auto lxr = Lexer<std::variant<MyTokenType, TokenErrors>, 5>{ };
    for (auto& x : lxr.final_states) {
        x = var;
    }
    return lxr;
}
```

Note: In the above code (the last snippet), and elsewhere, replacing the loop with `lxr.final_states.fill(var);` also makes no difference.

Comment: Hi, I can't change the error type to be first type because the code I provided was just reproducible part of entire lexer. I will need to make changes everywhere. Also, for the reading perspective, the first argument of variant should be a valid type, instead of error type, don't you think?

Comment: @AakashGupta Then, if you can't change *anything* about the variant, I think you're stuck with the bug and will have to either wait for a fix or use a different compiler (the clang-cl compiler that plugs into VS is happy with your code as-is).

Answer (score 0):

I reported the bug here: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/4286

It seems that the problem exists for almost 2.5 years now and there is no resolution yet.

As a workaround, as suggested in the GitHub link, the following code will compile without any problems:

```
constexpr auto res = foo();
```